# WSO2 DAS and APIM Gateway nodes stops publishing events

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

We've setup a WSO2 DAS 3.1.0 which receives events from our API Manager 1.10.0 setup.

We receive events from the API Manager Gateway nodes, we analyze them in streams and we finally output the results to an RDBMS.

When stress-testing this setup, for no apparent reason, after a few hours, the DAS-server stops publishing to the RDBMS (works just fine up until this point). It still seems like the DAS-server is still working; but at the same time, the Gateway-nodes starts complaining (on some occasions):

```
[PassThroughMessageProcessor-212] ERROR AsyncDataPublisher Event queue is full, and Event is not added to the queue to publish
```

Restarting the DAS-server gets it working again, but it's far from a reliable setup.

A few things:

1. Are there particular performance settings we should be looking into for DAS? We're currently running it with 2GB of java heap memory, and checking the JVM-metrics logs doesn't indicate that DAS is utilizing all resources (Around 80% CPU and around ~1.5GB of memory).
2. Any other areas to look into as to why DAS suddenly stops handling events? (and doesn't post any logs as to why it fails).
3. When we restart DAS, the gateway-nodes doesn't seem to start transmitting events again. Is there perhaps something that detects it can no longer send events which makes them "shut down" on sending events? Is there any way we can override this to make them start sending events again when it's possible?
4. How come there's no error logs at all in DAS for this? I assume DAS will log some kind of warning if it can't handle events quick enough, or if its queue begins to fill up etc?

(We tried changing the WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB from H2 to MS SQL, but the same behavior, with events not published after a few hours).

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when AyncPublisher's queue has been fully used up and it could not publish the events to DAS at the rate events are added. The first thing you can do here is increasing the event queue buffer size in Gateway nodes. It can be done by configuring "asyncDataPublisherBufferedEventSize" parameter in APIM_HOME/repository/conf/data-bridge/thrift-agent-config.xml. You can increase the value as follows.

```
<asyncDataPublisherBufferedEventSize>100000</asyncDataPublisherBufferedEventSize>
```

Let me explain little bit more about what happens underneath. Basically, when DAS receives events, event records are inserted into the DB (as batches). So DAS receiver TPS is depends upon the underline data storage. With RDBMS record stores, DAS receiver TPS is measured around 6000-7000 (which also depends on event size). So when we publish events to DAS in higher rates, DAS receiver side queues will get filled up and eventually publisher side queues also will get filled up and starts to drop events without adding for publishing.

So increasing the queue size as described above might resolve your issue but with very high TPS that is still may not be enough. If you want to achieve higher receiver TPS in your deployment it is recommended use HBASE as the event record store instead of RDBMS.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=50505742

Comment: Thank you for the information. In our case though, our tests send around 50-100 events / second, so it would be very strange if DAS couldn't keep up(?). The queue-size shouldn't be a problem (even though we've now raised them)-- as we should be able to process them in the speed they arrive in our "limited" case?